# Ansible using AWS interactions throws exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I was trying to run a playbook to automate AWS but i encountered this exception which I can't understand. I have the following playbook:

```
- name: Just for testing
  hosts: windows-server
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    aws_a_key: accesskey
    aws_s_key: secretkey
  tasks:
    - name: Ping
      win_ping:
    - name: Create a file to C:\Temp\test.conf
      win_file:
        path: C:\Temp\test.conf
        state: touch
    - name: Create another file to C:\Temp\test2.conf
      win_file:
        path: C:\Temp\test2.conf
        state: touch
    - name: Gather S3 facts
      aws_s3_bucket_facts:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_a_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_s_key }}"
        region: eu-central-1
```

When I try to execute it I get the following error:

```
PLAY [Just for testing] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Ping] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [WIN-40NQ43PHHA5]

TASK [Create a file to C:\Temp\test.conf] *************************************************************************************
changed: [WIN-40NQ43PHHA5]

TASK [Create another file to C:\Temp\test2.conf] ******************************************************************************
changed: [WIN-40NQ43PHHA5]

TASK [Gather S3 facts] ********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [WIN-40NQ43PHHA5]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Exception calling \"Create\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"At line:4 char:21
+ def _ansiballz_main():
+                     ~
An expression was expected after '('.
At line:12 char:27
+     except (AttributeError, OSError):
+                           ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:14 char:7
+     if scriptdir is not None:
+       ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:21 char:7
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):
+       ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:21 char:30
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):
+                              ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:21 char:25
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):
+                         ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At line:23 char:32
+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
+                                ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:23 char:33
+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'imp.PY_SOURCE' in expression or statement.
At line:23 char:32
+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
+                                ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:23 char:46
+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
+                                              ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.
\"
At line:6 char:1
+ $exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException

The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command 
name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
At line:7 char:2
+ &$exec_wrapper
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression
 ", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/mpolgardi/ansible/test_playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************
WIN-40NQ43PHHA5            : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Can someone help me decode this error? I have no idea where to even look. Also is there a way for ansible to give me readable error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/aws_s3_bucket_facts_module.html#requirements), use of `aws_s3_bucket_facts` requires python with both the `boto` and `boto3` modules available to it.

What *appears* to be happening to you is that the windows machine is trying to execute that `.py` file as if it were PowerShell, and (of course) those two syntaxes are wholly incompatible.

Do you have `ansible_python_interpreter` set to a working binary? It is *possible* that switching `gather_facts:` to `yes` will surface any misconfiguration earlier, although I can't swear to it since I don't know if the `winrm` connection pre-empts fact gathering using just PowerShell, and wouldn't notice a bogus `ansible_python_interpreter` value.

While this isn't *exactly* what you asked, it's also quite a common behavior to use `delegate_to: localhost` and/or `connection: local` for those AWS-y tasks, since there is little to no value in having those tasks run on the *target* machine, given that the credentials are already present in the playbook (that is: it doesn't acquire credentials from anything on the target machine). That presumes, naturally, that you have a local python which has `boto` and `boto3` installed in them, but that's presumably far more likely than convincing a random windows machine to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wanted to run the AWS commands locally in the first place, it never crossed my mind that it would try to run them on the target machine. Changing the hosts to localhost and setting the connection to local worked! Thank you.